# How to export the Excel sheet with cell data by column name in using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, excel, mean-stack, export-to-excel

I want to export the excel sheet, before export the excel sheet i want to declare the column name by code and that data only show as excel column header,
I want to set dropdown list in the particular column, the dropdown values are also declare by code.

here i have attached my excel sample image.

[image]
I searched lot but there is no use full.

Is it possible to do this in angularjs. Already i done this in `".net"` but  i don't know how to do this in angularjs. can anyone help me.

Comment: use this package to generate csv in backend using node.js http://csv.adaltas.com/

Comment: Hi nitin, after install csv pakage what should i do

Comment: you can use this package to create a JSON data with fields you require, generate csv, and then send that to client, use angularjs to download this file from client's browser.

Comment: @nitin can you send any example